# How to know which the last element is that you've entered into a std::array?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm making a mfc application to make a somewhat drawing mechanism. Using a polyline the user can draw figures, and on pressing the enter key the current point of the line is joined to the starting point[to form a closed polygon]. I think you get the idea. Now, I'm using an STL array to store each vertex of the polygon- in simple words, every point at which the left-mouse button is clicked while drawing the figure is stored in the array.

```
std::array<CPoint,11> v;   //vertices
```

I'm using the following mechanism to output the elements of this array, i.e the points:

```
  for(int j=0 ; j<v.size() ; j++ )
    {
        s.Format(L"%d %d\n",v[j].x, v[j].y);
        aDC.TextOutW(x+=20,y+=20,s );     //each time print the coordinates
        s=" ";                                    //at a different location
    }
```

During execution, when the user draws the figure by clicking points around the screen, those points are stored in the array. The array's declared with 12 elements, but rarely does a shape have 12 vertices. The rest of the element(the empty ones) remain (0,0)- and yet these are outputted in the loop. So what I get printed is 3-4 coordinates and a lots of (0,0)s. Is there a way to print only those elements in which the vertices are stored(I hope you get what I mean). Something like `vertices[n]=/*some character that signifies the last element*/` . My question is, what will this character be? like a '\0' in a string.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector` with an upfront call to `reserve`?  Then this becomes trivially easy _and_ you can support polygons with more than 12 vertices.

Comment: Why is `if (vertices[i].x != 0 && vertices[i].y != 0)` not good enough?

Comment: @ Nick  ohh sorry about that, thanks for pointing it out. There I've fixed it.

Comment: @ H2CO3 hey thanks, that worked! it somehow just never occurred to me.

Comment: @H2CO3 That would work only if the origin point `(0,0)` can be declared illegal, i.e. if no polygon can have a vertex at `(0,0)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You have a point here, but since OP stated that `(0; 0)` is used as "invalid point", I thought this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like there is a good candidate for an "end marker" in a [`CPoint`](http://www.oifii.org/ns-org/nsd/ar/cp/vst/niallmoody-com-ndcplugs_AmplitudeImposer_source-v22/vstgui_3_0_beta2/Documentation/html/struct_c_point.html) structure: every pair of `{x,y}` represents a legal point, at least theoretically.

If you insist on using a fixed array (presumably, for performance reasons), you can also store the number of polygon vertices in a separate variable (continuing your string analogy, that would be a "Pascal string" of points, rather than a "C string" of points).

If using an array is not essential, you may want to switch to a `std::vector<CPoint>`, a container that is better suited for representing structures of variable size, such as polygons.

Finally, you could designate one point as illegal (say, at `{std::numeric_limits<long>::max(), std::numeric_limits<long>::max()}`), create an instance of that point statically, and use it as an end-of-sequence marker. In this case, consider expanding your array by one, and use the end marker as a sentinel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you intend to use the `(0; 0)` point as invalid, you can just check a point for being at `(0; 0)`:

```
if (vertices[i].x != 0 && vertices[i].y != 0) {
    // valid
}
```